# Problems with object stored functions

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So, I have made a function that creates a new xmlhttprequest and takes an object which contains all the information needed to construct one as an argument. Everything works fine until I tell it what to do when the request is complete trough the object (default value for the function works perfectly.), For some reason it gives me an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"

```
window._={
xhr: function(a){
    if(typeof a.method==="undefined"||a.adress==="undefined"){
        console.log("Well, That's not going to work...");
    }
    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(a.method,a.adress,a.asyn);
    if(typeof a.headers!== "undefined"){
        Object.keys(a.headers).forEach(function (key) {
            x.setRequestHeader(key,a.headers[key]);
        });
    }
    if(typeof a.ready==="undefined"){
        a.ready=function(){console.log(x.responseText);}
    }
    x.send();
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){
            a.ready();
        }
    }
    }
}
window.onload = alert(_.xhr({method:"get",adress:"../php/include/functions.php?function=id_from_username&arg=kiddo",asyn:true,headers:{},ready:function(){console.log(x.responseText);}}));
```

(The url specified is a php file on my server which can execute functions within the file when given GET headers `?function=samplefunc&arg1=foo&arg2=bar` and optionally as many args as the function needs. In this case I'm telling it to look for a user with the name "kiddo" and return their id to my script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that you are accessing the variable x defined inside xhr function from outside it's scope.

Solution is to pass call the ready function with the response text from inside xhr function

```
window._={
    xhr: function(a){
        if(typeof a.method==="undefined"||a.adress==="undefined"){
        console.log("Well, That's not going to work...");
    }
    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(a.method,a.adress,a.asyn);
    if(typeof a.headers!== "undefined"){
        Object.keys(a.headers).forEach(function (key) {
            x.setRequestHeader(key,a.headers[key]);
        });
    }
    if(typeof a.ready==="undefined"){
        a.ready=function(){console.log(x.responseText);}
    }
    x.send();
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){
            a.ready(x.responseText);
        }
      }
    }
 }

window.onload = alert(_.xhr({method:"get",adress:"",asyn:true,headers:{},ready:function(responsText){console.log(responsText);}}));
```